# How to calculate expression of union of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set of solutions for the equation $\sin(x) = 0$

$$\{ n\pi \mid n \in Z \}$$

The set of solutions for the equation $\cos(x) = 0$ is

$$\left\{\frac{(2n + 1)\pi}{2} \mid n \in Z \right\}$$

The set of solutions for the equation $\sin(x)\cos(x) = 0$ is the union solutions to both equations.

$$\{ n\pi \mid n \in Z \} \cup \left\{\frac{(2n + 1)\pi}{2} \mid n \in Z \right\}$$

This expression can be simplified.

$$\left\{ \frac{n\pi}{2} \mid n \in Z \right\}$$

I found the simplified set by writing out the elements in the set and seeing the pattern. Is there some sort of operation that can be performed on $n\pi$ and $\frac{(2n + 1)\pi}{2}$ to obtain $\frac{n\pi}{2}$? How do I obtain the simplified set without writing out some of the elements and trying to find the pattern?

Comment: One way is to observe that $\sin x\cos x=\frac12\sin 2x$ so that $\sin x\cos x=0\iff\sin2x=0\iff 2x\in\{n\pi\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}\iff x\in\{\frac12n\pi\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$.

Comment: I want to know if there is a generalised method that can be applied to any two sets. $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ was just an example

Comment: That is the reason why I gave a comment, and not an answer. It might have been that you were not aware of what I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{n\pi|n\in \mathbb Z\}\cup \{\frac{2n+1}2\pi|n\in \mathbb Z\}=$

$\{\frac {2n}2\pi|n\in \mathbb Z\}\cup \{\frac{2n+1}2\pi|n\in \mathbb Z\}=$

$\{\frac {m}2\pi|m\text{ even};m\in \mathbb Z\}\cup \{\frac{m}2\pi|m\text{ odd};m\in \mathbb Z\}=$

$\{\frac m2|m\in \mathbb Z\}$

Comment: +1 Although that was to be my answer!